# Multiple windows accessing same terminal prompt

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, tty

There are numerous tools for using numerous terminal prompts from a single window, like `gnu screen`---but I'm wondering about the opposite.  I'd like to access *the same* prompt from different windows.  In particular, I'm using NoMachine to run a virtual desktop where there is a particular tty I'd like to access from a normal SSH session.  Is there a way to attach to the same tty session from the SSH session?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `screen` or `tmux` to attach to the same (remote) tty from multiple other source (client) locations.

But you might be asking how to make either `screen` or `tmux` gain control of an existing tty.  I don't know how to do that, but you could re-parent an existing process (perhaps even a shell) to a tty that is owned by `screen` or `tmux` using `reptyr`.  See one of multiple references on use of `reptyr`: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/623432/transfer-current-command-to-a-detachable-session-tmux-screen) or[here](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen).  Others exist, I'm sure.

Comment: Kind of wondering if screen would interfere with any VI(M) shortcuts, but probably not on a basic setup

Comment: Generally not, except where the `screen` shortcuts overlap with any VIM key-sequences.  By default, `screen` uses the prefix-key `Ctrl-a` to enter the screen command system, which messes up some things that use emacs-style key-bindings.  I have in my `.screenrc` a line to change the prefix to `Ctrl-j` --- `escape ^Jj`